# Application Server

Tags: tomcat

What are some factors that would drive me away from using Tomcat in production for an enterprise application. My company is not big, but a few departments, and it will be a dynamic site (db, web services).
I am not planning to use EJBs, but Spring and POJOs.
Beside EJBs, is there a technical reason about an application that would necessarily mean that I cannot use Tomcat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have successfully used Tomcat in production. There is no technical reason *not* to use it.

Comment: What in a web application would necessarily mean one cannot use Tomcat?
For instance, if you wanted to use EJBs, you cannot use Tomcat(i'm not planning to, just an example)

Comment: Not true - you can use EJBs if you add OpenEJB to your Tomcat deployment.  (ActiveMQ gives you MDBs as well.)

Comment: I would recommend staying on the Spring path rather than using OpenEJB.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any technical reasons, but you should consider your support options.  How mission-critical is the application?  Will you require 24-hour, instant on-demand support?  If so you will need to look for a 3rd party support provider.  If not, the tomcat community may be sufficient for support.

Answer (score 0):

I think that since Spring purchased one of the leading Tomcat support providers it's more viable than ever.  If you've got a small company with a limited budget, why not?